# loop through array forward and backward one at time?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

This is my first question and I hope to find an answer here.
I have an array

```
var arr = ['red', 'blue', 'black', 'green'];
```

I want to loop through it so I can `console.log();` an element every time I click a `btn` and keep tracking the index so I can iterate backward if I clicked a different btn.

```
nextBtn.addEventListener('click',nextItem)

prevBtn.addEventListener('click',prevItem)
```

Thanks

Comment: You kinda explain it yourself no? You have an index you're tracking. Every time forward is clicked, you add + 1 to the index and `console.log( arr[ index ] );` -1 for the back button.

Comment: If you want to avoid stepping outside of the array, you could do `index = Math.max(index + 1, arr.length - 1)` and the opposite for the other case, where you are decrementing.

Comment: I managed to achieve 
`var i = -1; `
`function nextItem(){
    i += 1;
    if (i > arr.length-1){
        i = 0;
    }
    console.log(arr[i]);

}`
but I can't do the backward.

Comment: Maybe `i -= 1` ??????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a closure over the index and return an object with the function for getting the next or previous value of the array.

```js
var array = ['red', 'blue', 'black', 'green'],
    index = function (i) {
        var out = document.getElementById('out');

        out.innerHTML = array[i];
        return {
            prev: function () {
                i && i--;
                out.innerHTML = array[i];
            },
            next: function () {
                i + 1 < array.length && i++;
                out.innerHTML = array[i];
            }
        }    
    }(0);

document.getElementById('nextBtn').addEventListener('click', index.next);
document.getElementById('prevBtn').addEventListener('click', index.prev);
```

```html
<button id="prevBtn">prev</button> <span id="out"></span> <button id="nextBtn">next</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

In each function you'd grab the current index of the element in the array by increment/deincrementing a global variable that keeps track of where you currently are. To prevent going over/under the array you'd provide a conditional in each.

```js
var arr = ['red', 'blue', 'black', 'green'];
var currentIndex = 0;

var nextBtn = document.getElementById('nextBtn');
var prevBtn = document.getElementById('prevBtn');

nextBtn.addEventListener('click', nextItem);

prevBtn.addEventListener('click', prevItem);

function nextItem() {
  if (currentIndex === (arr.length - 1)) {
    return;
  }
  
  console.log(
    arr[++currentIndex]
  );
}

function prevItem() {
  if (currentIndex === 0) {
    return;
  }
  
  console.log(
    arr[--currentIndex]
  );
}
```

```html
<button id="prevBtn">Prev</button>
<button id="nextBtn">Next</button>
```